# Prepending a first row to table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, prepend

I have a table in my code:

```
<table class="mainTable">
</table>
```

I want to prepend a head row to it.

```
var filter_all_head_row="
            <tr>\
                <th>smth</th>\
                                ...
                    <th>smth</th>\
                        </tr>
";
```

I'm trying to do it in onload of my page with this code:

```
$("table.mainTable").prepend(filter_all_head_row);
```

By the console says:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Solutions?

Comment: I think the better way is to arrange that html with +(plus) like
`'<tr>'+
  '<th>smth</th>'+`
etc!!

Comment: I think `/` is better due to this reason http://davidwalsh.name/multiline-javascript-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing at least two `\` in your string literal:

```
var filter_all_head_row="
    <tr>\
        <th>smth</th>\
        <th>smth</th>\
    </tr>
";
```

Should be:

```
var filter_all_head_row = "\
  <tr>\
    <th>smth</th>\
    <th>smth</th>\
  </tr>\
";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this [`solution`](http://jsfiddle.net/BluAngel/H4hSF/)

```
var filter_all_head_row = '<tr>\
   <th>smth</th>\
   <th>smth</th>\
 </tr>';
```

you wrote like this

```
var filter_all_head_row = '
......
```

It should be like this

```
var filter_all_head_row = '\
......
```

Because every time you want to go next line you have to put this `\`.
Also recommended  that use some `tool` like `Adobe Dreamviewer` etc they will show this type of `errors` during writing of you code